# If one product belong to two or over categories. How show the category Breadcrumbs at product page?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, nopcommerce, breadcrumbs

I meet the question: if customer view one product under a category, but this product belong to two categories, it just show the first [0] category name at breadcrumbs. how show the product breadcrumbs, if customer browse the products under category2, then at the breadcrumbs show Home/category2/productName, not Home/category1/productName, I think the customer will be feeling very strange for that, I saw that website [GreatFactoryZ.com](https://www.greatfactoryz.com), the product breadcrumbs show all the categories Home/[category1] [category2]/productName, I don't think is good solution, has anyone good solution ideas?

Comment: But in nopcommerce product can have only single category i think, Not sure as I have worked on v2.40 only.

Comment: " if customer browse the products under category2, then at the breadcrumbs show Home/category2/productName, not Home/category1/productName, " -- this is expected behaviour. are you expressing yourself correct? why should show category1 if customer is browsing category2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, can set products to just single category, but once have two category, it have that problem.I use nop3.6

Comment: batmaci, you can check, if have more parent categories, it just show first one category -- if have category[0] category[1], just can show category[0], so if one shoes belong to Mens shoes and Womens shoes, if you browser from Womens shoes category, click the products, then the breadcrumbs show like home/Mens shoes/product, so looks not good.